# how can i get values of Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData using power shell

Tags: powershell

```
$wmi = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface -ComputerName $computer -Namespace $namespace.
```

Using this power shell script how can I get the value of the parameters? i.e. how can I get the value of these:

- `BytesReceivedPerSec`
- `BytesSentPerSec`
- `BytesTotalPerSec`

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface -ComputerName $computer -Namespace $namespace 
| Select BytesReceivedPerSec, BytesSentPerSec, BytesTotalPerSec
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how i will get these values of these parameters in different variables and print this.Please help me to do this.I need to use only power shell but i am very new to this scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't enough?

```
$wmi = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface -ComputerName $computer | select Name, BytesReceivedPerSec, BytesSentPerSec, BytesTotalPerSec
```

You can also use .NET for statistic totals:

```
$wmi = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() | foreach {$_.name; $_.GetIPv4Statistics()}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how i will get these values of these parameters in different variables and print this.Please help me to do this.I need to use only power shell but i am very new to this scripting language.

Comment: Why you need more variable? `$wmi.BytesReceivedPerSec` or `$wmi.BytesSentPerSec` and so on can do it. In case you have more than one NIC you need to specifie the index array as `$wmi[0].BytesReceivedPerSec` for first NIC in array.